# Entity Framework 7 filtering a child collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I will try and specify this as simply as I can, I am using EF7.

I have two tables - Report, and ReportCategories, these are linked via a reportCategoryMap table which has a foreign key constraint to both tables (EF data model of both tables has hashset of reportcategorymap)

I want to filter upon report info but additionally want to filter the report categories that come back.  To simplify my query it is as follows

```
_dbContext.Reports.Where(r => r.reportId == 1)
                  .Select(r => new Report
                                {ReportId = r.ReportId,
                                 ReportCategoryMap = r.ReportCategoryMap.Where(rc => !rc.IsDeleted)
                                 }
```

The problem is that the ReportCategory objects in the returned ReportCategoryMap collections are always empty. I have tried putting in a

```
_dbContext.Reports.Include(r => r.ReportCategoryMap).ThenInclude(rcm => rcm.ReportCategory).Where ....
```

But this does not work.

If I remove the Select then the values come back but the CategoryMap is not filtered when Categories are not deleted.  I can always put the filtering logic after the query is run but hopefully I'm doing something foolish and someone can help me in the linq query

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It looks like your query is OK, except your simplified query technically wouldn't compile. You would need to surround `ReportId = r.ReportId, ReportCategoryMap = r.ReportCategoryMap.Where(...)` with curly braces, not parenthases. But I assume that's not your problem. Are you sure you're querying the data you think you are? If you're getting back empty collections for `ReportCategoryMap` and not getting an actual error, that would imply that all items are in fact deleted in your particular data set. What happens if you flip the `Where` clause to `rc => rc.IsDeleted`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for response.  The curly braces was just my bad simplification, have edited it now in post, but had curly braces in my proper linq query.  And they are definitely not deleted, all of them are flagged as false at the moment